# How to customize spinner with image arrow

Tags: android

I have a spinner that I need to change the arrow and make it within border

like this
[image]

I tried multiple things on stackoverflow 
Setting background drawable, setting the android:button ..etc but no luck. I get it but stretched or  I get the arrow in the list of selections, or  I get the selections covering the whole screen 
How can I get spinner with my own drawable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve your spinner custom background.

- Using 9 patch image (the easy way)
- Using [LayerList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) (the complex way)

Because I do not have your spinner background in `.png` extension so I will demo the second one.

The background contains 2 layers, the former is a rounded rectangle, the latter is an arrow bitmap.

Here is an arrow bitmap (`ic_arrow_24dp`), you can replace with your own.

[image]

**background_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <!-- First layer is a rounded rectangle -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#808080"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Second layer is a arrow bitmap -->
    <item android:gravity="right|center_vertical">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_24dp"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_spinner"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"/> <!-- Prevent content of the spinner from overlapping over the arrow icon, the size is equal to size of the arrow icon -->

</LinearLayout>
```